# Imaging one laptop to another

Tags: windows-10, imaging, distribution

I have a windows 10 laptop which I have managed to set-up as I like it.
I would like to image this laptop so I can deploy/install it on another one, which is exactly same model, for use as a back-up/second laptop for another employee.

What is the best way of doing this?

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: One word, DISM. Additionally, don't forget the licensing you'll need to keep you on the right side of the law with Microsoft...

Comment: There are a lot of disk imaging/copying utilities out there. What have you researched so far?

Comment: I consider that it seems that a system clone. Some software could achieve. For example:https://www.backup-utility.com/clone/clone-old-computer-to-a-new-one-4348.html